# Nginx - Error 404 after recompile

Tags: nginx

After recompiling my Nginx (to install PageSpeedModule), I put the new Nginx to my "/usr/sbin/" folder then I restarted Nginx.
But, all my sites are now in 404 error. I took a look to my "/etc/nginx/" folder, and all it's ok, I have my sites enabled configured.
It seems that Nginx don't take my config file, or use another folder. How can I repair this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look in your error.log and access.log files. They might reveal some helpful information. Paste them in your question if you can't work it out from there

Comment: I don't have any message in error.log and access.log since I used the new compiled Nginx.

Comment: Ok, Nginx have now a new folder in "/usr/local/nginx" with new configuration files. Can I change this to use "/etc/nginx" ?